# Почему file_get_contents('php://input') возвращает NULL

Tags: php, telegram-bot, docker

делаю простенький телеграмм бот.
установил хуки - ngrok для работы на локальном сервере.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сервер через docker.
не могу отловить данные который прислал клиент, всегда приходит NULL? почему так!??
Но когда я данные записую в файл .txt, ассоциативный массив записует[image: введите сюда описание изображения]ся.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как ее исправить !?

```html
$dataClint =  file_get_contents('php://input');
$updateClint = json_decode($dataClint,true);
var_dump($updateClint);
```

Comment: попробуйте без json_decode
$dataClint =  file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($updateClint);

Comment: приходит пустая строка
$dataClint =  file_get_contents('php://input');

var_dump($dataClint);

/var/www/src/public/index.php:27:string '' (length=0)

Answer (score 0):

А точно ли отправляется json?

Что-то такое попробуйте посмотреть:

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) === 'application/json') {
    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $request_body = json_decode($request_body, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        echo "JSON error";
        exit();
    }

    var_dump($request_body);
    exit; 
} else {
    var_dump($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать !

Comment: пустая строка ' '

Comment: пустая строка - это скорее пустой (не переданный) контент. Как проверяете? Попробуйте что-то вроде curl -L -i -X PUT -d '{"data": "test data"}' -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://вписать_сюда_url_вашей_точки_входа

Comment: $config = [
    [
        'body' => '{"offset":null,"limit":null,"timeout":null}',
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-type' => 'application/json'
        ],
    ]
];

$responseUpdates = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $_ENV['TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'] . '/getUpdates', $config);

$updates = $responseUpdates->getBody();

$updates = json_decode($updates);

var_dump($updates);
данные приходит от бота.  только вот как дернуть с него данные , много многомерный

Comment: т.е. у вас данные все же приходят, но как POST? Я так понимаю вы же получили результат в массив $updates в последнем комментарии

Comment: да дынные пришли) разобрался, это чистая api телеграмм ! пришло 8 массиво в обьекте , думал думку как теперь с этим веселиться.. )